# Decent sweat-resistant headphones with mic (ie, iPhone compatible)

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, hardware-recommendation, headphones

Similar to this question already posed: [Decent headphones with a Mic for Android and iPhone](http://gadgets.stackexchange.com/questions/1411/decent-headphones-with-a-mic-for-android-and-iphone), I'm looking for a pair of decent sweat resistant headphones that are good for working out.

Originally I used the default headphones that came with my iPhone, but as they got wet with sweat, one or the other earbud would stop functioning temporarily... eventually after many workouts, the 'phones just died (I'm assuming it's the sweat, since I have another set of the same headphones from a similar period that work fine)

I'm currently using [these](http://www.airdrives.com/default.asp?contentID=22) but the problem is they are exhibiting the same problem as my original earbuds and I'm questioning whether they'll eventually die.

So I'm looking for:

1. A stereo headset with microphone so I can answer calls and do voice commands
2. Ones that are made to be sweat resistant and durable
3. (Preferably) bluetooth so I can put my phone in my pannier or on the treadmill shelf.

Anyone with suggestions?

Comment: Thanks all, I've bought the blackberry and waterproof headphones (as they're quite inexpensive) and will test out to see which one fits best (and will mark as answered appropriately).

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Hardware recommendation ("let's go shopping") questions are off-topic here. Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use the default Blackberry wired headset which I get on [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001T3UDOA).

I wear them only when I ride my bike to talk on the phone (call family on the 2 hour bike ride to work, its a good time to chat on the way home) or listen to podcasts.

While they may not be sweat resistant, they are cheap.  I buy them on Amazon for $2.85 a pair and the noise cancelling seems to be pretty good, considering I often talk while riding a bike in traffic and wind.

I have had one mike die due to sweat, but otherwise, they seem to last reasonably well.  And I sweat copiously, alas.

I love the single click to mute, hold to drop the call, and hold to activate voice dialing on my Blackberry.   Now to figure out how to get the BB voice dialer to call via Google Voice so I can call my parents in Canada without long distance charges from the US.

Comment: Reviews say the padding keeps falling off... what are your experiences with that?  Price is definitely right, almost disposable at that price.

Comment: Ya, the padding falls off pretty fast.  Mostly because I carry them in my pocket.  However, even without the padding I do not find them uncomfortable.

Comment: I ordered 4 in my last purchase.  The first pair, I popped one right off while holding it in my pocket.  The second pair (that I am currently using) the padding came off, but are otherwise fine. 

As you not.  At under $3, they are basically disposable, and since they last a month or three each, still reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using Motorola [MOTOROKR S9 BT Stereo Headphones](http://www.store.motorola.com/MOTOROKR-trade-Bluetooth-Stereo-Headphones/dp/B003H0HIE6/178-5250067-8057758) very successfully (outdoors, gym) for past 1.5 yrs. All 3 of your points fit to the T. They are a bit expensive but the experience & usability is worth it. The link I have posted is the HD (High Def) version, you may not need that. You may also want to check deals on Amazon, they almost always have better price.

PS: See if you can try it on first. It fits nicely on my frame but I've heard they're not always as comfortable on others.

Comment: The most helpful review (critical) on the Amazon page: http://www.amazon.com/Motorola-S9-HD-Headset-Adapter-Gloss/dp/B001EKQQ5S
seems to indicate it's not good for jogging or sweat resistance.  Also the non-replaceable battery and short cycle-life make me wary.  How did the 'phones work out for you, and how long have you had them?

Answer (score 1):

Could you maybe get swimmers headphones (completely water resistant) and a headphone - microphone adapter. Would cost more than the disposable blackberry approach but be better for the environment.

Comment: Great idea... I might be happy to ditch microphone if waterproofing keeps the headphones free of my sweat.

Comment: Chose this answer because I bought some, they fit and although they're not as comfortable, do a pretty good job.

Answer (score 1):

When I was in the Apple shop Liverpool the other day I noticed some Sennheiser/Adidas ones, the [CX680i](http://www.sennheiser.co.uk/uk/home_en.nsf/root/private_headphones_sport-line_504603), which look like they would fit your requirements perfectly.